# Aggregate values in rows conditional on values in another column using r

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
Moves <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Men <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1, NA, 0.05, 0.05, NA)
Women <- c(0.4, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.05)

df <- tibble(Moves, Men, Women)
```

Now I would like to aggregate the values in the rows where the number of moves are equal to 3 or more in the columns Men and Women. So I want the data to look like this:

```
Moves Men Women
0     0.5 0.4
1     0.3 0.5
2     0.1 NA
≥3    0.1 0.1
```

I have some problems figuring out how to do this. Most posts about related issues is on how to aggregate values between columns, but here I want to do it within columns based on a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `case_when` to change the 'Moves' that are greater than or equal to 3, to `>=3`, use that as grouping variable and `summarise` the other columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Moves = factor(case_when( Moves >=3 ~ '>=3', 
       TRUE ~ as.character(Moves)), levels = c('0', '1', '2', '>=3'))) %>%
     summarise(across(everything(),  ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA_real_ 
           else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Moves   Men Women
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0       0.5   0.4
#2 1       0.3   0.5
#3 2       0.1  NA  
#4 >=3     0.1   0.1
```

---

Or using `fct_collapse` from `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
df %>% 
  group_by(Moves = fct_collapse(as.character(Moves), 
  `>=3` = as.character(Moves[Moves >=3]))) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(),  ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA_real_  
        else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), .groups = 'drop')
```